# Issue with Drawer navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a drawer navigation component to my react native project. I am new to react navigation. While using the [code from here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation), I am getting error as mentioned below.

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:118.
    in DrawerNavigator (at ProfileScreen.js:30)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    ...
```

Code in my ProfileScreen.js file :-
[image]

Why am I getting this error and how to fix this?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: Please post the actual code and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

i also use the snack code which you share link. I copy paste the whole code and install these two dependencies.

```
 npm install @react-navigation/drawer@^5.x
 npm install @react-navigation/native@^5.x
```

the code is working fine for me...
i think you have dependencies issue. you have to install these two dependencies.

Comment: Yes this solved the `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at createDrawerNavigator.tsx:118.
    in DrawerNavigator (at ProfileScreen.js:30)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    ...`issue, but raised a new issue which goes like -: `Error: Unable to resolve module ./views/DrawerToggleButton`

Comment: Here is my dependencies list from package.json 


`"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.9",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",`

I did some researches and found that `DrawerToggleButton` is present in `@react-navigation/drawer` version 6. Have a look [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/main/packages/drawer/src/views)